# How to make contents of <pre><code></code></pre> render correctly in IE7?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, internet-explorer, line-breaks

I make the following AJAX pull with JQuery using JSON to an ASP.net Web Service:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "TestWebService.asmx/Foo",
data: "{}",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
    $("#justpre").html(msg.d);
    $("#precode").html(msg.d);
} } );
```

The TestWebService implements a very simple WebMethod Foo() that returns the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Foo() {
    return "multi" + Environment.NewLine + "line" + Environment.NewLine + "comment";
}
```

Finally, I display the result

`<pre id="justpre"></pre>`

`<pre><code id="precode"></code></pre>`

Firefox and Chrome display the returned value as a multi-line comment just fine. IE7, however, renders it as a single-line with no line breaks.

```
FF, Chrome:
multi
line
comment

IE7:
multi line comment
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

IE has some known issues with manipulating text upon inserting it into a pre tag.

Here is some more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html

Your best bet may be to sniff for IE and replace the \n characters with `<br />` elements OR sniff for IE and use the IE only innerText, instead of innerHTML. Something like

```
document.createTextNode("multi\nline\ncomment");
```

might also do the trick in a cross browser way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "pre" tag, try using CSS on the parent tag

```
.theParentTagOfPre {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[More Info on white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp)